# Lists, String Split Options and logic

Tags: c#

I am in need of help a little help from someone more advanced. The code i have questions about is the following :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> numbersAsStrings = Console.ReadLine()
                         .Split('|')
                         .Reverse()
                         .ToList();
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    foreach (var str in numbersAsStrings)
    {
        numbers.AddRange(str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(int.Parse)
                            .ToList()
                             );
        // Zapiswam stoinostite ot stariq List w nov List
        // Smeneni sa oshte gore s .Reverse
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers));
}
```

The exercise was as following: Write a program to append several array of numbers.

1. arrays are separated by ‘|’.
2. Values are separated by spaces (‘ ’,one or several)
3. Order the arrays from the last to the first, and their values from left to right.

Can someone explain to me how the code reads the entries on this particular code please. I could not find the solution myself.

Kind regards

Comment: You should post the code in your question rather than a link.  The link may go stale, or the linked code may change.

Comment: As an aside to @Neil's point, many of us don't like clicking random links online as well. The more you can put directly into your question, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` will read all the characters typed in after the program has been run, until the user presses enter.

```
 List<string> numbersAsStrings = 
    Console.ReadLine() // read the input as a string
    .Split('|')  // split the string into an array (delimited by |)
    .Reverse()   // reverse the array
    .ToList();   // convert the array into a List
```